# New Case - Watered the battery and got rust on one of the engine pipe

Tags: battery, car, rust

I bought new car and I added battery water to level. But some spilled on the engine and one of pipe got effected and it has rust on it.

I went to mechanic, he told me to apply diesel on it. I did, but still I can see the rust.

Please help and I am adding images as requested.

[image: engine pipe rust]
[image: below engine rust]

Comment: Are you sure? Where I live, "battery water" is just distilled water. There isn't anything in it to promoting rust and corrosion. You can't remove rust by applying diesel to it.

Comment: Yes, It was battery water, I saw after that there was a white foam where it dropped, then in couple of days, when i removed that foam, rust was below it.

Comment: OK, so what's your question?

Comment: my question is how to take care of that rust, should i be worried and why so quickly this water re-acted this way and ate the paint on the pipe ?

Comment: That all depends on what the pipe is, where it is located and how big the rust spot is. Could you post up a picture?

Comment: not at the moment, I can get it for you tomorrow evening. but it's a pipe going into the engine and spot is like 2.5 inches. Thanks

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that "battery water" is simply distilled water. You sure it wasn't acid? It would definitely make rust. Anyways, the only way to get rid of rust is to grind it off.

Comment: I'm pretty sure vicky's using acid as water wouldn't foam up, nor leave rust behind in such short order. A picture of the effected area would allow us to help out quite a bit here. Also, a picture of the "battery water" you were using would be awesome as well.

Comment: Yes, here I get acid water for battery. They prepare it locally in there shop.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is probably cosmetic. Perhaps in a decade or two the exhaust system will rust away, but since water is a byproduct of combustion, your system will have plenty of rust from the inside.

Is this some highly valuable show car? If not, it doesn't matter.

If it bothers you, you can apply Naval Jelly, rinse thoroughly, sand lightly, and then apply Header or Exhaust Paint in the color of your choice.

Comment: Note that "Naval Jelly" is a brand name for a gel-like product that contains Phosphoric acid.  You can find many rust removers that use this common chemical.

Comment: Good point, @JPhi1618. The actual brand of rust remover is unimportant.

Comment: If the OP caused the situation using acid, how is more acid going to help? I would think neutralizing the acid would be the first line of business by using some baking soda.

Comment: Naval Jelly type rust removers will temporarily remove rust, and also leave a light coating of phosphate that has a moderate ability to prevent rust, similar to parkerizing on military rifles. Nonetheless for best rust resistance, a follow-up coating of heat resistant paint or other plating is desirable.

Comment: @kmarsh  +1 for using 'parkeriziing'.  I will upvote when my votes come back.